# MySQL does not honor a varchar column size change

Tags: mysql, .net, varchar

I have a MySQL instance running under Windows 8.1(dev machine).  I have a table defined with one of the columns as varchar(50).  I need to change it to varchar(100).  When I do this in mysql workbench, the change is made and everything looks good.  Problem is that when I run the .net app that uses the database, if I send data with more that 50 characters I get a column too long error.  Even after stoping/starting the database.

Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: try, SHOW DESCRIBE YOURTABLE;  - if the field there 50 Chars, so the bug is in your apllication

Comment: that is not a command @BerndBuffen

Comment: sorry without show.  > DESCRIBE YOURTABLE;

Comment: DESCRIBE YOURTABLE shows the length to be 100.  My code is not sending that many characters, so I don't see how it's my code.  If i manually change the column value in my code before sending to 50 characters or less it works.